# c# "$ " operator not working in window 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a code to append my key value

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> d in data)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strData)) strData = $"{d.Key}={d.Value}";
   else strData += $"&{d.Key}={d.Value}";
}
```

This piece of code is working in window 10 with framework 4.5.2 with vs2017 , but i copy this code to window 7 with the same frame work ,but different VS , which is 2013 , it return error for

> Unexpected character '$'

I have no idea what is the problem , is it VS versioning problem ? what is the best way to reproduce this code in VS2013 ?

Comment: The framework and .NET version have no impact here; it's a new *compiler* feature. You need a compiler which supports version 6 or better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# 6, which added the string interpolation feature, was released in 2015. Editor support wasn't back-ported for older versions. This has nothing to do with the .NET Framework or operating system version.

You can achieve the same thing using string concatenation:

```
strData += "&" + d.Key + "=" + d.Value;
```